# JBoss eap 6: sub deployment in jboss-structure.xml was not found

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x, seam, jboss-eap-6, seam2

I managed to run my ( seam 2.2.2 / jsf 1.2 / hibernate 3.5.6) application on JBoss eap 6.3 (which is compatible with AS 7.[something I don't know]), now to update to JBoss 6.4.4 I'm having such problems:

```
09:27:23,363 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS017100: Escutando no 127.0.0.1:4447
09:27:23,363 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS017100: Escutando no 127.0.0.1:9999
09:27:23,680 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."Sinapse.ear".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Sinapse.ear".STRUCTURE: 
JBAS018733: Failed to process phase STRUCTURE of deployment "Sinapse.ear"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [jboss-as-server-7.5.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1980) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1913) [jboss-msc-1.1.5.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.1.5.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018746: Sub deployment Sinapse-ejb.jar in jboss-structure.xml was not found. Available sub deployments: 
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.subDeploymentNotFound(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:275) [jboss-as-server-7.5.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.module.descriptor.DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.deploy(DeploymentStructureDescriptorParser.java:184) [jboss-as-server-7.5.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-4]
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [jboss-as-server-7.5.4.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.5.4.Final-redhat-4]
    ... 5 more

09:27:24,157 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014612: Falha na operação ("deploy") - endereço ([("deployment" => "Sinapse.ear")]) - falha na descrição: {"JBAS014671: Falha de serviços" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"Sinapse.ear\".STRUCTURE" => 
"org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"Sinapse.ear\".STRUCTURE: JBAS018733: Falha ao proceder com a fase STRUCTURE do deployment \"Sinapse.ear\"
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS018746: A sub-implantação Sinapse-ejb.jar no jboss-deployment-structure.xml não foi encontrada. Sub-implantações disponíveis: "}}
09:27:27,029 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) JBAS015859: Implantado "Sinapse.ear" (runtime-name: "Sinapse.ear")
09:27:27,031 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Relatório
 de status de serviço JBAS014777: Serviços que falham na inicialização:      service jboss.deployment.unit."Sinapse.ear".STRUCTURE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."Sinapse.ear".STRUCTURE:
 JBAS018733: Falha ao proceder com a fase STRUCTURE do deployment "Sinapse.ear"

09:27:27,216 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: A interface do gerenciamento ouvindo no http://x.x.x.x/management
09:27:27,216 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: O console de administração ouvindo no http://x.x.x.x
09:27:27,217 ERROR [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015875: JBoss EAP 6.4.4.GA (AS 7.5.4.Final-redhat-4) iniciado (com erros) em 14241ms - Iniciado 158 de serviços 188 (1 serviços falharam ou faltam dependência, os serviços 48 são lazy, passivos ou em demanda)
09:27:27,264 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Implantação encerrada Sinapse.ear (runtime-name: Sinapse.ear) em 2ms
09:27:27,584 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015858: Desimplantado "Sinapse.ear" (runtime-name: "Sinapse.ear")
09:27:27,584 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Relatório
 de status de serviço JBAS014777: Serviços que falham na inicialização:      service jboss.deployment.unit."Sinapse.ear".STRUCTURE
```

Sorry, some parts of the log are badly translated to portuguese.

The config files that work with EAP 6.3:

Application.xml:

```
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:application="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" 
         version="5">

  <display-name>Sinapse-ear</display-name>
  <module>
    <ejb>Sinapse-ejb.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <java>jboss-seam.jar</java>
  </module>
  <module>
    <java>jboss-seam-remoting.jar</java>
  </module>
  <module>
    <java>jboss-el.jar</java>
  </module>
  <module>
    <java>jbpm-jpdl.jar</java>
  </module>
  <module>
    <java>antlr-runtime.jar</java>
  </module>
  <module>
    <java>mvel2.jar</java>
  </module>
  <module>
    <java>richfaces-api.jar</java>
  </module>
  <module>
    <java>richfaces-ui.jar</java>
  </module>
  <module>
    <java>richfaces-impl.jar</java>
  </module>
  <module>
    <java>resteasy-jaxrs.jar</java>
  </module>
  <module>
    <java>jboss-seam-resteasy.jar</java>
  </module>
  <module>
    <java>commons-digester.jar</java>
  </module>
  <module>
    <java>commons-beanutils.jar</java>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>quartz.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <ejb>JoSQL-1.9.jar</ejb>
  </module>
  <module>
    <java>gentlyWEB-utils-1.1.jar</java>
  </module>
  <module>
    <java>jai_codec.jar</java>
  </module>
  <module>
    <java>jai_core.jar</java>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
        <web-uri>Sinapse.war</web-uri>
        <context-root>/sinapse</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
</application>
```

jboss-deployment-structure.xml:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">  
    <deployment>  
        <dependencies>  
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" export="true"/>  
            <module name="org.dom4j" export="true"/>  
            <module name="org.apache.commons.collections" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.slf4j" export="true"/> 

            <module name="org.javassist" slot="main" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.transaction" slot="main" export="true"/>

            <module name="org.hibernate" slot="3" export="true" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.validator" slot="3" export="true" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.commons-annotations" slot="3" export="true" />

            <module name="org.apache.lucene" slot="main" export="false"/>  
            <module name="org.hibernate.search" slot="3" export="true" />

            <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2" export="true"/>  
            <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="1.2" export="true"/> 

            <module name="org.bouncycastle" slot="main" export="true" />
            <module name="org.quartz" slot="main" export="true"/> 

            <module name="br.sinapse.conf" slot="main" export="true"/> 
        </dependencies>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.hibernate" slot="main" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.validator" slot="main" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.commons-annotations" slot="main" /> 
            <module name="org.hibernate.commons-annotations" slot="3" />

            <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="main"/>  
            <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="main"/>  

            <module name="org.jboss.as.jsf" slot="main"/> 
            <module name="org.jboss.as.jsf-injection" slot="main"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.as.weld" slot="main"/> 

            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider" slot="main" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>  
    <sub-deployment name="Sinapse-ejb.jar">
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.apache.log4j" export="true"/>  
            <module name="org.dom4j" export="true"/>  
            <module name="org.apache.commons.collections" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.slf4j" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.javassist" slot="main" export="true"/>
            <module name="javax.transaction" slot="main" export="true"/>

            <module name="org.hibernate" slot="3" export="true" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.validator" slot="3" export="true" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.commons-annotations" slot="3" export="true" />

            <module name="org.apache.lucene" slot="main" export="true"/>  
            <module name="org.hibernate.search" slot="3" export="true" />

            <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2" export="true"/> 
            <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="1.2" export="true"/> 

            <module name="org.quartz" slot="main" export="true"/> 

            <module name="br.sinapse.conf" slot="main" export="true"/>     

            <module name="org.infinispan" slot="main" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.msc" slot="main" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan" slot="main" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups" slot="main" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.as.clustering.api" slot="main" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.as.clustering.common" slot="main" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.as.clustering.impl" slot="main" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups" slot="main" export="true"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.as.clustering.service" slot="main" export="true"/>

            <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate" slot="3" export="true" />
        </dependencies>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.hibernate" slot="main" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.validator" slot="main" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.commons-annotations" slot="main" />
            <module name="org.hibernate.commons-annotations" slot="3" />

            <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="main" />
            <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="main" />

            <module name="org.jboss.as.jsf" slot="main"/> 
            <module name="org.jboss.as.jsf-injection" slot="main"/>            
            <module name="org.jboss.as.weld" slot="main"/> 

            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider" slot="main" />
        </exclusions>   
    </sub-deployment>
    <sub-deployment name="Sinapse.war">   
        <dependencies>  
          <module name="org.apache.log4j" export="true"/>  
          <module name="org.dom4j" export="true"/>  
          <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" export="true"/>  
          <module name="org.apache.commons.collections" export="true"/> 

          <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="1.2" export="true"/>  
          <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="1.2" export="true"/> 

          <module name="org.hibernate" slot="3" export="true" />
          <module name="org.hibernate.validator" slot="3" export="true" />

          <module name="org.apache.lucene" slot="main" export="true"/>  
          <module name="org.hibernate.search" slot="3" export="true" />
        </dependencies>  
        <exclusions>  
          <module name="org.hibernate" slot="main" />
          <module name="org.hibernate.validator" slot="main" />
          <module name="org.hibernate.commons-annotations" slot="main" />
          <module name="org.hibernate.commons-annotations" slot="3" />

          <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-hibernatevalidator-provider" slot="main" />

          <module name="javax.faces.api" slot="main"/>  
          <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" slot="main"/> 

          <module name="org.jboss.as.jsf" slot="main"/>           
          <module name="org.jboss.as.jsf-injection" slot="main"/>
          <module name="org.jboss.as.weld" slot="main"/> 
        </exclusions>  
    </sub-deployment>   
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Ear structure:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
lib/
JoSQL-1.9.jar
META-INF/application.xml
META-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml
antlr-runtime.jar
commons-beanutils.jar
commons-digester.jar
gentlyWEB-utils-1.1.jar
jai_codec.jar
jai_core.jar
jaxrs-api.jar
jboss-el.jar
jboss-seam-remoting.jar
jboss-seam-resteasy.jar
jboss-seam.jar
jbpm-jpdl.jar
lib/hibernate-entitymanager.jar
lib/infinispan-core-5.2.10.Final-redhat-1.jar
lib/itext-rtf.jar
lib/itext.jar
lib/jasperreports-3.7.5.jar
lib/jasperreports-chart-themes-3.7.4.jar
lib/jsf-facelets.jar
resteasy-jaxrs.jar
richfaces-api.jar
richfaces-impl.jar
richfaces-ui.jar
Sinapse-ejb.jar
Sinapse.war
```

I have tried many different changes but couldn't make it.

Comment: There's a lot of things that don't look right about this configuration. Hibernate, RESTEasy, JAX-RS, etc libraries should not be included. The list of module inclusions/exclusions in the `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` don't look right and the `application.xml` modules seem to be rather excessive.

Answer (score 1):

Check the location and content of you jboss-deployment-structure.  It should be placed in the top level deployment, in META-INF (or WEB-INF for web deployments)